# Find max value row in datagridview and change it's color

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to find max value row in `datagridview` and change it's `color`.

```
int maxValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("max(Score)", string.Empty));

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)`

{
  string clr = dt.Rows[0]["Score"].ToString();

  if (clr == maxValue.ToString())     
   {
     showdata1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
   }
}
```

Error in  my code.

[image]

Comment: At which line in your code are you getting this exception ?

Comment: This is not a question. This is a code dump.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the `DataTable` and using the index of `DataTable` iteration loop to get the `GridView` Row. The GridView has pages, when you try to access GridView particular row as per the index of `DataTable` you get exception. For example you have **20** Record in `DataTable` but only **10** in `GridView` then when you are in 11 iteration and try to access eleventh row of GridView through loop variable `i` you get exception.

Use the page number and page size to get the loop start and end index.

```
for (int i = PageIndex*PageSize; i < (PageIndex+1)*PageSize); i++)
```